# Profile Groups in Spring Boot 3 not working

Tags: java, spring, yaml, profile

After the migration to Spring Boot 3 it's not possible to activate multiple profiles in profile specific files. Instead Profile Groups should be used.

Unfortunately I can't get them to work, here is the snippet from my yml config:

```
spring:      
    profiles:
          group:
            local: debuglogin, profile_a, profile_b, profile_c
```

I have tried this in `application-local.yml`. Did anyone had the same experience?

Comment: I assume you have them as `spring.profiles.group.local ... `, right? And it should go in `application.yaml`

Comment: also, iirc, that `local` is a _list_, so something like : `spring.profiles.group.local: - debuglogin`  (and all others defined as a list)

Comment: it should work locally. so the application-local.yml should be loaded. I've also tried different variants, with spring.profiles.group.local: - debuglogin...spring.profiles.group.local: - "debuglogin"... and so on

Comment: and local is an active profile? this is visible in spring logs

Comment: yes local is active..but the other ones do not get activated

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example? like a github repo?

Comment: yes: https://github.com/Ciag2/spring-boot-3-profiles-test.git

Comment: i've added an application-local.yml. If you start the app with profile local it should load the other profiles as well. in the spring logs only local is active.

Comment: I don't see `debuglogin` being defined anywhere though

Comment: it's defined in the application-local.yml: https://github.com/Ciag2/spring-boot-3-profiles-test/blob/main/gs-spring-boot-main/complete/src/main/java/application-local.yml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250925/discussion-between-eugene-and-wash).

Comment: the current documentation is saying to use profile groups, which i did: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles.groups

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the issue. I was adding this code block in the profile specific file like application-local.yml instead it should be added in the application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      local: debuglogin, profile_a
      integration-test: debuglogin, profile_b
```

this should work if added in the application.yml but not in profile specific files.

Comment: So my _first_ comment was right.